# Unexpected value when parsing long long from argv

Tags: c, types

I'm a Python programmer trying to break my way into C. Could anyone help me to understand this unexpected behaviour?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int modulo(int a, int b) {
    return a - b * (a / b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("The largest possible LLu is %llu.\n", -1LLu);
    unsigned long long x = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned long long i;
    printf("Finding the largest prime number less than %llu.\n", x);
    for(i = 2; i < (x / 2) + 1; i ++) {
        if(modulo(x, i) == 0) {
             i = 2;
             x--;
        }
    }
    printf("Found %d.\n", (int)x);
return(0);
}
```

And then on the terminal:

> ./prog 111111111189
>
> The largest possible LLu is 18446744073709551615.
>
> Finding the largest prime number less than 18446744073151513109.

The program, however, works as expected for some very much larger numbers (sill less than the maximum LLu) and for smaller numbers too.

I'm very confused!

Many thanks!

Comment: Also, why that `modulo` function? Why not the `%` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, C has a built-in modulo operator, `%`. There's no reason to make your own.

Second, your modulo function only takes `int` values, and `atoi` returns an `int`. So your program is limited to the range of an `int`, not an `unsigned long long`.

And last, if it's working as you expected it to, then your expectations are broken since it won't give correct output because numbers are being truncated all over the place.

Comment: Thanks David! I'm not used to having to be this careful with my typing!

Answer (score 1):

`atoi()` returns an `int` the value you enter at command line overflows an `int` use `atoll()` instead, or even better use [strtoll()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) which is more flexible and unlike `atoi()` can handle overflows:

```
atoll(argv[1]);
//or 
strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```

Comment: I ended up correcting my modulo() function to accept LLu, and then used strtoull() instead of atoi(). Thanks for your answer though!